# Can I create singleton child class?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, singleton

I have a parent class:

```
class ParentClass {
public:
    ~ParentClass(){}
    static ParentClass &getInstance() {
        static ParentClass instance;
        return instance;
    }

    void methodA() {
        //do some stuff
    }

    void methodB() {
        //do some stuff
        methodA();
        //do some stuff
    }

private:
    ParentClass(){}
}
```

I want to create child class:

```
class ChildClass : public ParentClass {
public:
    ChildClass(){}
    ~ChildClass(){}

    methodA() {
        //do some stuff
    }
}
```

This code have some obvious problems. First of all I can't create `ChildClass` in this way (parent's constructor is private). And seems like `ChildClass` can't directly inherited from `ParentClass`. These classes are very similar. And I do not want to create two similar copies of these classes.

Probably I can create one base class for `ParentClass` and `ChildClass`. I'm not sure but does some method exist for creating childs from singleton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Singleton has a well defined target. It has to make sure that only a single instance of the given type exists in the current environment.

Thus I don't see any good reason to have `methodA` and `methodB` are inside it. Especially that no one can create an object of type `ParentClass` and thus cannot call `methodA` and `methodB` (unless they also become static).
I think a better OOD would be to create the singleton only with `getInstance()` method and separately create `ParentClass` which would contain a reference to the object which is returned by the singleton:

```
class SingletonClass {
public:
    ~SingletonClass (){}
    static SingleInstanceClass &getInstance() {
        static SingleInstanceClass instance;
        return instance;
    }

private:
    SingletonClass (){}
}

class ParentClass {
public:
    ParentClass(SingleInstanceClass& ref);
    ~ParentClass(){}

    virtual void methodA() {
        //do some stuff
    }

    void methodB() {
        //do some stuff
        methodA();
        //do some stuff
    }

private:
    SingleInstanceClass& singInstRef;
}
```

And then

```
class ChildClass : public ParentClass {
public:
    ChildClass(SingleInstanceClass& ref) : ParentClass (ref){}
    ~ChildClass(){}

    virtual void methodA() {
        //do some stuff
    }
}
```